# How do you order the results of a parameter drop down in DevExpress

Tags: parameters, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a DevExpress report with a parameter that is set by:

```
        var param = new Parameter();
        param.Name = "schemeName";
        param.Type = typeof(System.String);
        param.Description = "Scheme: ";
        param.Visible = true;

        var lookupSettings = new DynamicListLookUpSettings();
        lookupSettings.DataSource = ds;
        lookupSettings.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
        lookupSettings.DisplayMember = "SchemeName";
        lookupSettings.ValueMember = "SchemeName";

        param.LookUpSettings = lookupSettings;

        report.Parameters.Add(param);
        report.FilterString = "[SchemeName] == [Parameters.schemeName] or [Parameters.schemeName] == '' ";
```

Is there a way to get it to order the results from here so they are displayed alphabetically within the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the sort order within the parameter data source itself not the DynamicListLookUpSettings.

> The parameters do not support defining the sort order at the level of the DynamicListLookUpSettings class or its base LookUpSettings class and the values are displayed in the order they come from the data source. Thus, I suggest that you pre-sort the data at the data source object level before assigning the DynamicListLookUpSettings.DataSource property value.

Source: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T484324/dynamiclistlookupsettings-sort-datasource

Comment: The problem with that is that the sort order for the dataset is not the same as the sort order for the parameter (so AccountNumber for the dataset but the parameter is the insurance company)

Comment: Can you not do any of the following: Use different data sources for the parameter and report, order the data source for the parameter by insurance company and then order the generated report accordingly by account number or instead of assigning the current data source to the lookupsettings extract the parameter values before as a list which you can order and then assign to the parameters?

Comment: Hmm, that could be a posisble solution.  I'll have to see how practical it is to implement.

Answer (score 0):

> Report Parameters
>
> you can sort its data using the LookUpSettings.[SortOrder](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.DynamicListLookUpSettings.SortOrder#tabpanel_syntax_tabid_DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.DynamicListLookUpSettings.SortOrder-csharp) and
> LookUpSettings.[SortMember](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.DynamicListLookUpSettings.SortMember#tabpanel_syntax_tabid_DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.DynamicListLookUpSettings.SortMember-csharp) properties.

via https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/New-2018-2.xml#reporting

so this feature works out-of-the-box without custom datasource for parameter